# How to save images by name as 1,2,3,....n in android

Tags: android, android-studio

My app contains the camera functionality. I have develop the app.
As the app get starts one ListView of stations will popup(Like Station1, Station2,Station3....) & user has select one item from it. Then it will open the camera activity. So once the user took a picture, the image has to be stored like '**Station1_1**', '**Station1_2**', '**Station2_1**', '**Station2_2**' inside gallery. I have covered with the initial station name(Station1, station2..). But how do I store the last portion because it contains the sequence for each Station. So is there any way to save the images by 1,2,3....?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way but it isn't appropriate. If you just want to store each image having last portion is different then you can do in the following ways:-

1. You can call **API** for just handling counter.
2. You can store counter in **PREFERENCE**, but it won't work perfect if user clear data then new images were override old one.
3. You can store **TIMESTAMP** as end portion and it is appropriate way.